# React component rendering children from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider the following format of a simple web app in React. The app has a bottom toolbar containing the buttons use for navigating the application. The button content changes depending on what page you're viewing in the application.

```
function App(props) {
  return (
    <div className="page">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Homepage />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/login">
          <Login />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
      <Toolbar />
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
function Homepage(props) {
  const nextButton = <a href="/login">Continue to login</a>
  return (
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
  )
}
```

```
function Login(props) {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const nextButton = <button onClick={()=> login(email, password)}>Login</button>
  return (
    <input type="email" onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
    <input type="password" onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
  )
}
```

```
function Toolbar(props) {
  return (
    <nextButton />
  )
}
```

What would be a good way to lift the contents of the toolbar up or pass those contents from sibling components?

Comment: In your `<Toolbar />` component is it not possible to determine what to render depending on the current route?

Comment: Sure but the components to render are encapsulated in each "screen" since they sometimes require variables scoped to that "screen" demonstrated in `<Login />`

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first thing that comes to mind is to use context APIs.
We can create a context for example:
`ToolbarContext` or something. Then in that context keep toolbar config object.

```
// context file 


// Sample object ( this object will be set from another component by using context and setConfig method

// { url: '/', text: 'Continue to login'}

const [toolbarConfig, setConfig] = useState({});

// then as usual wrap the app in context provider and pass this `toolbarConfig` and the `setConfig` method down to all the components.
```

Then Inside the `Toolbar` component sync data from context.

After that, In each component, when the component loads, change that config object which is in context by setting proper URL and text ( here code will be in useEffect hook ).